# DataGridView Searching and Sorting

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview

Good afternoon
I had a question about how to sort and search the VB from DataGridView . It is necessary that the search is searched for only by ID (preferably without integrated solutions such as LINQ), 
Sorting should work through the combo box, and sort them by name or date

I would really appreciate if you help me

Work Example

[image]

Comment: What exactly is "the WB"??  Read [ask] and take the [Tour] - generally, you would search the datasource not the control.  Also, if you consult the usage guidance text for the tags, this cant be related to VB.NET ***and*** vba

Comment: Populate a `DataTable` with your data, bind that to a `BindingSource` and bind that to the grid. You can then search, sort and filter via the `BindingSource`. Before you ask, no I'm not going to provide an example. I have provided keywords that you can now search on and find out how to do what's required. Once you think you know what to do, do it. If it doesn't work, post what you did and then we can help you fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a concept for for you to try.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1
    Dim ds As New DataSet

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=EXCEL-PC\SQLEXPRESS; Integrated Security=true; Initial Catalog=NORTHWND")
        con.Open()
        Dim da As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Categories", con)
        da.Fill(ds, "Cat")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("Cat")

    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        ds.Tables("Cat").DefaultView.RowFilter = "[CategoryName] LIKE '*" & TextBox1.Text & "*'"
    End Sub

End Class
```

[image]

To filter as you type, which is what I think you want to do, try the script below.

```
Private Sub textBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim style As New DataGridViewCellStyle()
    style.Font = New Font(dataGridView1.Font.FontFamily, Me.Font.Size, FontStyle.Bold)
    style.BackColor = Color.Yellow
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dataGridView1.Rows
        For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
            If cell.Value IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Me.textBox1.Text) AndAlso cell.Value.ToString().Contains(Me.textBox1.Text) Then
                cell.Style = style
            Else
                cell.Style = dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle
            End If

        Next
    Next
End Sub
```